# Do Not Duplicate VALUE if already exist on MySQL

Tags: php, sql, duplicates

I've been trying to accomplish this, but as other issues I just can't figured it out. I've been reading around for posibles solutions but non of them goes along with my code, or if they do I can't figure out how or where to use them.

I have a DB where a user sends records. The database consist in few tables containing the Following "**Name, Lastname, Phone**". If any of this values is duplicate,  I would like my code to identify and **Ignore** the submission of the Form **if ALL this VALUES already exist on the DB**.

Here is my code:

```
        <?php

        $con = mysql_connect("HOST","USER","PASS");
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);
        $sql="INSERT INTO people (Name, LastName, Phone)
        VALUES
        ('$_POST[Name]','$_POST[LastName]','$_POST[Phone]')";

        if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
          {
          die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
          }
        
        echo "Record Added";

        mysql_close($con);
        ?>
```

Comment: You want to set a `UNIQUE` key on your table.  Also, your code is **wide open** to SQL injection, and you **will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to use prepared queries with PDO or similar.

Comment: @Brad Just a unique key will not do the trick. you have to INSERT IGNORE, or you will get errors when you try to add duplicates.

Comment: @SamHuckaby, Right... wouldn't you want to catch that and deal with it in some way?  `IGNORE` is likely the last thing you would want to do in a situation like this.  Perhaps you want to prompt the user that the data already exists or something.

Comment: @Brad, I'm just experimenting with this type of coding for now. I'm trying to figure few things before going deeper in other stuffs. I really appreciate your comment and letting me now about this issue, I'll have it on the ToDo list. But for now I just need an option or idea to accomplish the idea. Thanks!

Comment: @Edwinrif, Stop trying to learn `mysql_*` and at least switch to `mysqli`.  At a minimum, you must escape your data.  Even if for some reason you weren't considered about security, consider that if someone were to enter a quote mark in an input box, your query will fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `mysql_*` function are all deprecated now, and should NEVER be used. change your code to do something like the following:

```
//Set up a PDO connection to MySQL
$host = 'host_name';
$dbname = 'database_name';
$user = 'user_name';
$pass = 'user_pass';
try
{
    $DB = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass); 
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}

//Determine whether the appropriate values have been passed.
if(isset($_POST['Name']))
{
    $name = $_POST['Name'];
}
else
{
    echo "You must provide a name!";
        exit; //This may not be what you want to do here, it's an example action
}

if(isset($_POST['LastName']))
{
        $name = $_POST['LastName'];
}
else
{
    echo "You must provide a last name!";
        exit; //This may not be what you want to do here, it's an example action
}

if(isset($_POST['Phone']))
{
        $name = $_POST['Phone'];
}
else
{
    echo "You must provide a phone number!";
        exit; //This may not be what you want to do here, it's an example action
}


//Set up the query using anonymous values
$sql="INSERT INTO people (Name, LastName, Phone) VALUES ('?','?','?')";
$sth = $DB->prepare($sql);

try
{
        //Attempt to execute the insert statement
        $sth->execute(array($_POST[Name], $_POST[LastName], $_POST[Phone]));
        echo "Record Added";

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
        //If the insert failed, then you can handle the error, and determine
        //what further steps need to be taken.
        echo "Record Not Added";
}
```

Here's another question with a similar setting, that may also be useful to you:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10414922/1507210

Comment: This does not answer the OP's question.

Comment: Not only is your query subject to being hacked via injection, but it also does not work without the proper `UNIQUE` constraint being set on the table.

Comment: @Brad I have information at the end about setting up a unique key, and I used his query for brevity.

Comment: @SamHuckaby You should add information about setting up that key to your answer.  Also, it is dangerous to post insecure code like you have.  Lots of folks who don't know better will simply copy and paste it.  Code in answers should be of high quality.

Comment: @Brad, I appreciate your point, and I'm updating my answer as we speak. I'll show how to set up a PDO connection, and test if the value was added and give the error. :) Thank you for your constructive criticism.

Answer (score 0):

search in the table before insert

```
 <?php

        $con = mysql_connect("HOST","USER","PASS");
        if (!$con)
          {
          die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
          }

        mysql_select_db("testdb", $con);

        $name =  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[Name]);
        $LastName=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[LastName]);
        $Phone=  mysql_real_escape_string($_POST[Phone]);

         $search_res=mysql_query("SELECT * from people where Name='$Name' OR LastName='$LastName' OR Phone='$Phone'");

        if(mysql_num_rows($search_res) < 1){

             $sql="INSERT INTO people (Name, LastName, Phone)
             VALUES
                ('$Name','$LastName','$Phone')";

               if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
              {
              die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
              }

        echo "Record Added";
       }else{
          echo "User Already exits";
       }

        mysql_close($con);
        ?>
```

Comment: don't forget to parse the form field values by mysql_real_escape_string() or use mysqli if using new version of PHP

Comment: -1, this code is subject to SQL injection attacks and should not be used.

Comment: see the comment above, I am only explaning how to search from db and not insert the duplicate records.

Comment: Put it in your code, and I'll remove the downvote.  Also consider what happens if someone does an `INSERT` in between your `SELECT` and `INSERT`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this easy solution

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE Column = 'value' ");

if( mysql_num_rows($result) < 1) {
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('value') ");
}
```

Comment: This is not adequate.  Values can be inserted in between your two queries.

Comment: It is an idea for you modify it to get rid of duplicate entries